# how do I sound the console bell in Eclipse (Java)?

Tags: java, eclipse

The title fully describes the problem.

The following have both been silent.

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
System.out.print('\u0007');
```

Edit: This problem was observed on Eclipse 3.5.2 and ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug report suggests it is an ubuntu 10.10 problem.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/beep/+bug/677870

Answer (score 4):

Simply

```
Display.getCurrent().beep();
```

Comment: What if I want what was originally a console program to be a Swing program?  Should I still use SWT to beep a Swing program?  What if I don't need windows at all and want it to remain a console program?

Comment: Ahhh... I work with Eclipse plugins, thus SWT, all the time and silently - and wrongly - assumed that everybody else does the same :-) But... I don't know about how to do this in Swing...